# Solving a system of equations involving the floor function.

Tags: number-theory, systems-of-equations, fractions, integers, ceiling-and-floor-functions

I have the following system of equations that I am stuggeling with:

> $$ax\lfloor y\rfloor=k,by\lfloor x\rfloor=d$$

And I know that $x$ and $y$ are bigger than zero and all the other constants are natural numbers. Given is that $a$ divides $k$ and $b$ does not divide $d$.

What is the way to go on this problem?

**Thanks for any advice**

Comment: Hint: write $x=\lfloor x\rfloor+\alpha$ where $\alpha\in\left[0,1\right)$.

Comment: @Jan Thanks, but I do not really see why that is true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Assignment**:
>
> Solve:
>
> $$
> \begin{cases}
> \alpha x\left\lfloor\text{y}\right\rfloor=\gamma\\
> \\
> \beta\text{y}\left\lfloor x\right\rfloor=\Delta
> \end{cases}
> $$
>
> For $x\space\wedge\space\text{y}\in\mathbb{R}_{>0}$, where we know that $\alpha\mid\gamma$ and $\beta\nmid\Delta$ it is also given that $\alpha\space\wedge\space\gamma\space\wedge\space\beta\space\wedge\space\Delta\in\mathbb{N}$.

---

**Solution**:

Because we know that $\alpha\mid\gamma$, we can divide both sides of the first equation by $\alpha$ to get:

$$
\begin{cases}
x\left\lfloor\text{y}\right\rfloor=\frac{\gamma}{\alpha}\\
\\
\beta\text{y}\left\lfloor x\right\rfloor=\Delta
\end{cases}\tag1
$$

Now, I am going to decompose $x$ and $\text{y}$ in there integer part and there fractional part, as follows:

- $$x=\left\lfloor x\right\rfloor+\text{a}\tag2$$
  Where we know that $\text{a}\in\left[0,1\right)$.
- $$\text{y}=\left\lfloor\text{y}\right\rfloor+\text{b}\tag3$$
  Where we know that $\text{b}\in\left[0,1\right)$.

Now, we put $(2)$ and $(3)$ into $(1)$, in order to get:

$$
\begin{cases}
\left(\left\lfloor x\right\rfloor+\text{a}\right)\left\lfloor\text{y}\right\rfloor=\frac{\gamma}{\alpha}\\
\\
\beta\left(\left\lfloor\text{y}\right\rfloor+\text{b}\right)\left\lfloor x\right\rfloor=\Delta
\end{cases}\tag4
$$

Multiplying out gives:

$$
\begin{cases}
\left\lfloor x\right\rfloor\left\lfloor\text{y}\right\rfloor+\text{a}\left\lfloor\text{y}\right\rfloor=\frac{\gamma}{\alpha}\\
\\
\beta\left\lfloor x\right\rfloor\left\lfloor\text{y}\right\rfloor+\beta\text{b}\left\lfloor x\right\rfloor=\Delta
\end{cases}\tag5
$$

Now, we can solve:

$$
\begin{cases}
\text{a}\left\lfloor\text{y}\right\rfloor=\frac{\gamma}{\alpha}-\left\lfloor x\right\rfloor\left\lfloor\text{y}\right\rfloor\\
\\
\beta\text{b}\left\lfloor x\right\rfloor=\Delta-\beta\left\lfloor x\right\rfloor\left\lfloor\text{y}\right\rfloor
\end{cases}\tag6
$$

It is not hard to notice that the RHS of the first equation in $(6)$ is an integer and this also holds for the RHS of the second equation in $(6)$. Now, we can see that we can write $\text{a}$ as quotient involving the $\left\lfloor\text{y}\right\rfloor$ and this similarly holds for $\text{b}$. So I write:

$$\text{a}=\frac{\text{m}}{\left\lfloor\text{y}\right\rfloor}\space\space\space\wedge\space\space\space\text{b}=\frac{\text{n}}{\beta\left\lfloor x\right\rfloor}\tag7$$

So, we see that:

$$
\begin{cases}
\text{a}\left\lfloor\text{y}\right\rfloor=\underbrace{\frac{\gamma}{\alpha}-\left\lfloor x\right\rfloor\left\lfloor\text{y}\right\rfloor}_{=\space\text{m}\space\ne0}\\
\\
\beta\text{b}\left\lfloor x\right\rfloor=\underbrace{\Delta-\beta\left\lfloor x\right\rfloor\left\lfloor\text{y}\right\rfloor}_{=\space\text{n}\space\ne0}
\end{cases}\tag8
$$

Now, let's substitute $(7)$ into $(5)$, to get:

$$
\begin{cases}
\left\lfloor x\right\rfloor\left\lfloor\text{y}\right\rfloor+\text{m}=\frac{\gamma}{\alpha}\\
\\
\beta\left\lfloor x\right\rfloor\left\lfloor\text{y}\right\rfloor+\text{n}=\Delta
\end{cases}\tag9
$$

Now, multiply the first equation from $(9)$ with $-\beta$ and add the first and second equation from $(9)$, to get:

$$\text{n}-\beta\text{m}=\Delta-\frac{\beta\gamma}{\alpha}\space\Longleftrightarrow\space\text{n}=\Delta-\frac{\beta\gamma}{\alpha}+\beta\text{m}=\Delta+\beta\left(\text{m}-\frac{\gamma}{\alpha}\right)\tag{10}$$

Now, we know that $x>0$, so we know that $\left\lfloor x\right\rfloor\ge0$ but when dividing by it it can not be equal to $0$, this implies that $\left\lfloor x\right\rfloor\ge1$. We know that $\text{b}$ is positive so $\text{n}$ must also be positive, so:

$$\text{n}=\Delta+\beta\left(\text{m}-\frac{\gamma}{\alpha}\right)\ge0\space\Longleftrightarrow\space\text{m}\ge\frac{\gamma}{\alpha}-\frac{\Delta}{\beta}\tag{11}$$

But, because we know that $\text{m}$ is an integer, we also know that:

$$\text{m}>\left\lfloor\frac{\gamma}{\alpha}-\frac{\Delta}{\beta}\right\rfloor\tag{12}$$

Because we know that $\text{a}\in\left[0,1\right)$, we get:

$$\text{a}=\frac{\text{m}}{\left\lfloor\text{y}\right\rfloor}\space\Longrightarrow\space\left\lfloor\text{y}\right\rfloor>\left\lfloor\frac{\gamma}{\alpha}-\frac{\Delta}{\beta}\right\rfloor\tag{13}$$

Now, given that $x\left\lfloor\text{y}\right\rfloor=\frac{\gamma}{\alpha}$, we see that:

$$x<\frac{\frac{\gamma}{\alpha}}{\left\lfloor\frac{\gamma}{\alpha}-\frac{\Delta}{\beta}\right\rfloor}\tag{14}$$

> Now, you know that:
>
> $$1\le\left\lfloor x\right\rfloor<\left\lfloor\frac{\frac{\gamma}{\alpha}}{\left\lfloor\frac{\gamma}{\alpha}-\frac{\Delta}{\beta}\right\rfloor}\right\rfloor\tag{15}$$
>
> So:
>
> $$\left\lfloor x\right\rfloor\in\left\{1,\dots,\left\lfloor\frac{\frac{\gamma}{\alpha}}{\left\lfloor\frac{\gamma}{\alpha}-\frac{\Delta}{\beta}\right\rfloor}\right\rfloor\right\}\tag{16}$$
>
> And you can test all possible values of that using $(1)$.

Comment: Thank you very much. I am going to study your answer in detail.

Comment: @Derik You're welcome, I am glad that I could help you.